# multi tag filter not getting product info in shopify using custom code withou app

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

i have created custom code sidebar filter. if filter by one tag its working fine, suppose if we click another tag no product details are showing.

Snippet/sidebar-filter.liquid

```
{% for block in section.blocks %}
  {% assign heading = block.settings.filter_heading %}
  {% assign tags = block.settings.filter_tags | split: ','  %}
  <div class="collection-filter-tag-category">
    <h4> {{ heading }} </h4>
    <div class="filter-li-scroll">
      {% for t in tags %}
      {% assign tag = t | strip %}
        {% if current_tags contains tag %}
          <li class="active">
              {{ tag | link_to_remove_tag : tag }}
          </li>
        {% else %}
          <li class="">
              {{ tag | link_to_add_tag : tag }}
          </li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Templates/collection.liquid:

```
 {% section 'collection-template' %}
```

Templates/collection-template.liquid:

```
<div id="collection-product-filter-pane">
    <div class="sidebar_filter">
        {% include 'sidebar-filter' %}  
    </div>
    <div class="page-width" id="Collection">
      {% if section.settings.layout == 'grid' %}
        {% case section.settings.grid %}
        {% when '2' %}
          {%- assign grid_item_width = 'medium-up--one-half' -%}
        {% when '3' %}
          {%- assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium-up--one-third' -%}
        {% when '4' %}
          {%- assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium-up--one-quarter' -%}
        {% when '5' %}
          {%- assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium-up--one-fifth' -%}
        {% endcase %}

        <div class="grid grid--uniform{% if collection.products_count > 0 %} grid--view-items{% endif %}">
          {% for product in collection.products %}
            <div class="grid__item grid__item--{{section.id}} {{ grid_item_width }}">
              {% include 'product-card-grid', max_height: max_height %}
            </div>
          {% else %}
            {% comment %}
            Add default products to help with onboarding for collections/all only.

            The onboarding styles and products are only loaded if the
            store has no products.
            {% endcomment %}
            {% if collection.handle == 'all' and collection.all_vendors.size == 0 and collection.all_types.size == 0 %}
              <div class="grid__item">
                <div class="grid grid--uniform">
                  {% for i in (1..limit) %}
                    <div class="grid__item {{ grid_item_width }}">
                      <div class="grid-view-item">
                        <a href="#" class="grid-view-item__link">
                          <div class="grid-view-item__image">
                            {% capture current %}{% cycle 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 %}{% endcapture %}
                            {{ 'product-' | append: current | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
                          </div>
                          <div class="h4 grid-view-item__title">{{ 'homepage.onboarding.product_title' | t }}</div>
                          <div class="grid-view-item__meta">
                            <span class="product-price__price">$19.99</span>
                          </div>
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  {% endfor %}
                </div>
              </div>
            {% else %}
              {%- assign is_empty_collection = true -%}
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      {% else %}
        <div class="list-view-items">
          {% for product in collection.products %}
            <a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}" class="list-view-item">
              {% include 'product-card-list', product: product %}
            </a>
          {% else %}

            {% comment %}
            Add default products to help with onboarding for collections/all only.

            The onboarding styles and products are only loaded if the
            store has no products.
            {% endcomment %}
            {% if collection.handle == 'all' and collection.all_vendors.size == 0 and collection.all_types.size == 0%}
              {% for i in (1..4) %}
                <a href="#" class="list-view-item">
                  <div class="list-view-item__image-column">
                    <div class="list-view-item__image-wrapper">
                      <div class="list-view-item__image">
                        {%- assign placeholder = 'placeholder-product-' | append: i -%}
                        {% include placeholder %}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="list-view-item__title-column">
                    <div class="list-view-item__title">{{ 'homepage.onboarding.product_title' | t }}</div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="list-view-item__price-column">
                    <span class="product-price__price">$19.99</span>
                  </div>
                </a>
              {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
              {%- assign is_empty_collection = true -%}
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      {% endif %}

      {% if is_empty_collection %}
        <div class="grid__item small--text-center">
          <p class="text-center">{{ 'collections.general.no_matches' | t }}</p>
        </div>
      {% endif %}

      {% if paginate.pages > 1 %}
        {% include 'pagination' %}
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

if filter by another tag no product list coming
[image]

please help me to get result, I'm stucking two days pls someone help me

Comment: I think when you make more than one tag filters into Shopify it works on the condition of and, means need to tag exists into products, you can check it editing a single product and add both tags to product and test again.

Comment: i not getting any data when using more than one tag, {{ collection.product }} returns empty,then how do I code?